# C major chord in four-part, close harmony

Tags: piano, chords, chord-voicings

What tones would you use if told to strike the common chord of C in four-part, close harmony, using the root for the highest tone?

Answer (score 3):

[image: close position C chord]

---

A C chord is composed of the tones C, E, and G. The root is C. In a four-part chord, the bass is typically also the root. So, we have a C in the bass and a C in the soprano. A close position chord indicates that the alto should be the closest harmonizing note (beneath the soprano) and the tenor should be the next closest harmonizing note coming down.

Because this is a four part harmony, the bass doesn't have to be the next lowest harmonizing note. The interval between the tenor and the bass can be as large as we wish. In this case it is a tenth.

Comment: It's very strange to call C the fundamental, I think that term should be saved for the basis of an overtone series. Root is the better term for the C in a C-major chord.

Comment: I would've thought the phrase "close harmony" implied [this meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Close_and_open_harmony&oldid=591362216), i.e. that the notes are within an octave of one another, rather than a "closed position chord" (which I think is what you're referring to). But I'll admit I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes, that is what a the close position is, but in a four part harmony, the bass is exempt from the closest harmonizing note rule. If there are three voices in closed position, they will always be within one octave.

Comment: @American Luke offers a perfectly good voicing for SATB.  But it isn't 'close harmony'.

Comment: @LaurencePayne it totally is. See https://music.utk.edu/theorycomp/courses/murphy/documents/PartWritingRules.pdf.

Comment: Piston's _Harmony_ is in line with @AmericanLuke, in 4 parts only the SAT are close.

Comment: Yes, the rule for SATB writing keeps the upper voices closer than the lower two.  But this question isn't about general principles of SATB.  It's about a 4-note chord in close position.

Answer (score 2):

You would arrange the 4 notes as closely as possible.

C, E, G, C.   One of these in my picture. Or a further octave transposition to be pedantically complete, but the first one will do for a theory exam question!

Despite the 'Piano' tag and the word 'strike' in the question, some people have assumed this MUST be about SATB writing, and have described a typical SATB voicing that is not 'close position'.  (Though my first example is quite possible as SATB.)

[image]

Comment: Close.  Voicing the notes of the chord as closely together as possible.  No gaps. What ISN'T clear is the re-definition of 'close' in @American Luke's answer.

Comment: Laurence, this is incorrect. It's a closed voicing, but not four part SATB. In SATB, only the SAT need to be closed the bass is not expected to be part of that closed voicing. See https://music.utk.edu/theorycomp/courses/murphy/documents/PartWritingRules.pdf. The phrase "strike" does not override the usage in 4 part harmony you can even see it in this other question: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/37796/open-close-position-chords-what-i-am-missing/

Comment: Why is everyone assuming this is about SATB?  It's tagged 'piano'!   I agree,  SATB doesn't usually DO close harmony.

Comment: Because the OP says "four-part ... harmony". Because of the [tag:piano] tag, the interpretation of the question is ambiguous.

Comment: "The term "four-part harmony" refers to music written for four voices, or for some other musical medium—four musical instruments or a single keyboard instrument" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-part_harmony

Comment: SATB is the typical 4 part harmony and even if not writing for vocals the typical voice leading techniques are used. It's not a bad assumption and the fact it's called out should at least be mentioned. Focusing on the alternative interpretation with explanation rather than calling another answer wrong/misleading would be a better path.  I'll also note that Wikipedia itself has flagged that article as: "This article needs attention from an expert in Classical music. The specific problem is: A lot of information on this page seems completely incorrect. See examples on the talk page."

Comment: I agree, SATB doesn't typically do close harmony. But that's what this question is about!   Close voicing.  Not the open voicing more typical of SATB writing.  I've simplified my answer to make this completely clear.

Comment: "Despite...": Indeed, _close harmony_ is usually used to describe harmony sung by all-male or all-female groups rather than mixed groups.